# Android - Textview in ConstraintLayout not resizing properly to fit its contents because of parent's padding

Tags: android, overflow, padding, android-constraintlayout

I'm trying to do a pretty basic thing: I have a ConstraintLayout with a TextView inside and I want the TextView to resize according to its contents. However, right now the TextView overflows and is not fully displayed. The culprit is the ConstraintLayout's padding. Any ideas how to fix it while keeping the padding? (I have more elements inside the ConstraintLayout, so I don't wanna put a margin on each one of them instead of the parent's padding)

Image (from Android Studio's layout editor, but the result is the same during runtime):

[image]

Code:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/msg_in_bg"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:maxWidth="240dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtMessage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/messageTxt"
        android:text="@{item.text}"
        tools:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi vel ex nec massa tincidunt dapibus eget quis nulla. Sed tristique justo sed vehicula congue. Nullam varius lacinia sagittis. Sed consectetur sit amet erat fringilla vehicula. Donec dapibus elit eu mauris congue, a dapibus mi laoreet. "
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Consider to remove `android:maxWidth` in the layout file.

Comment: I would like to keep the maxWidth, because I don't want the text to be too wide.

Answer (score 1):

Move the `android:maxWidth` attribute from the parent `ConstraintLayout` into the `TextView`. You'll also want to adjust it to consider the padding (i.e. change it to `220dp` instead of `240dp` since you'll have 20dp of horizontal padding).

After doing that, there's no need for the `app:layout_constrainedWidth` attribute.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/msg_in_bg">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtMessage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/messageTxt"
        android:text="@{item.text}"
        android:maxWidth="220dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        tools:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi vel ex nec massa tincidunt dapibus eget quis nulla. Sed tristique justo sed vehicula congue. Nullam varius lacinia sagittis. Sed consectetur sit amet erat fringilla vehicula. Donec dapibus elit eu mauris congue, a dapibus mi laoreet. "/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```